# Trying to compile this dapp and i get this error, I do not know what to make of it, as the files are all there

Tags: yarnpkg, hardhat

PS C:\Users\MOON AI\Desktop\New folder\mantle_crowdfunding-dapp> yarn hardhat compile
yarn run v1.22.19
$ "C:\Users\MOON AI\Desktop\New folder\mantle_crowdfunding-dapp\node_modules.bin\hardhat" compile
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: Cannot find module '@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\MOON AI\Desktop\New folder\mantle_crowdfunding-dapp\hardhat.config.js
- C:\Users\MOON AI\Desktop\New folder\mantle_crowdfunding-dapp\node_modules\hardhat\internal\core\config\config-loading.js
- C:\Users\MOON AI\Desktop\New folder\mantle_crowdfunding-dapp\node_modules\hardhat\internal\cli\cli.js
- C:\Users\MOON AI\Desktop\New folder\mantle_crowdfunding-dapp\node_modules\hardhat\internal\cli\bootstrap.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
  at Object. (C:\Users\MOON AI\Desktop\New folder\mantle_crowdfunding-dapp\hardhat.config.js:5:2)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'C:\Users\MOON AI\Desktop\New folder\mantle_crowdfunding-dapp\hardhat.config.js',
  'C:\Users\MOON AI\Desktop\New folder\mantle_crowdfunding-dapp\node_modules\hardhat\internal\core\config\config-loading.js',
  'C:\Users\MOON AI\Desktop\New folder\mantle_crowdfunding-dapp\node_modules\hardhat\internal\cli\cli.js',
  'C:\Users\MOON AI\Desktop\New folder\mantle_crowdfunding-dapp\node_modules\hardhat\internal\cli\bootstrap.js'
  ]
  }
  error Command failed with exit code 1.
  info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
  PS C:\Users\MOON AI\Desktop\New folder\mantle_crowdfunding-dapp>

yarn hardhat compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yarn install @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).